# Como corrigir "dancinha" (flicker) de webfont de ícones ao fazer reload da página?

Tags: css, css-font-face

Ao fazer reload da página os ícones de um webfont são carregados somente depois do carregamento do CSS e isso ocasiona uma "dancinha" no texto.

Veja abaixo o comportamento indesejado do ícone quando se faz reload da página:

[image: bug webfont]

O código fonte do meu CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"icons";
    src:url("../fonts/icons.eot");
    src:url("../fonts/icons.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../fonts/icons.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/icons.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}

.i {
    font-family:"icons";
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:1;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
    speak:none;
    text-decoration:inherit;
    text-transform:none;
    text-rendering:auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
}

.i--menu:before {
    content:"\f117";
}
```

Comment: Esse problema é chamado de `flicker` normalmente. O Paul Irish fez um post sobre o assunto: [`Fighting the @font-face FOUT`](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/) Dá uma olhada também no seguinte material: [`Introduction to the Google WebFont Loader`](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-google-webfont-loader-and-how-to-avoid-font-face-text-flickering-with-it/)

Comment: Bruno, qual é a fonte que você está carregando nesse exemplo?

Comment: @Romulo é um custom utilizando o grunt-webfont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar uma destas opções `<link>` com *prefetch* dentro de `<head>`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="prefetch" href="(url)">
    </head>
```

Então sendo as fontes CSS você deverá adicionar assim no `prefetch`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="prefetch" href="fonts/icons.eot">
        <link rel="prefetch" href="fonts/icons.eot?#iefix">
        <link rel="prefetch" href="fonts/icons.woff">
        <link rel="prefetch" href="fonts/icons.ttf">
    </head>
```

> Eu adicionei o `fonts/icons.eot?#iefix` pois o sinal de `?` faz a url ser considerada outra.

### Diferenças

Existe um método chamado `prerender` e isto confunde algumas pessoas, segue as diferenças:

- `prefetch` (pré carregar):

  Isto é usado para buscar e fazer cache dos "resources" para que depois possa ser usado na navegação [especificação HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#link-type-prefetch), talvez este já atenda o caso do uso das fontes.

  > **Nota:** Aparentemente não é suportado pelo Safari (Mac OSX) ainda
  >
  > Lista de navegadores com suporte:
  >
  > - Internet Explorer 11+
  > - Edge 12+
  > - Chrome 8+ e Opera 15+ (coloquei junto pois usam a mesma tecnologia, o Chromium)
  > - Firefox 2+
- `prerender` (pré renderizar):

  É usado para pré-renderizar uma página completa que provavelmente será usada em uma próxima navegação.

  > **Nota:** O problema do `prerender` é que ele ainda não é suportado pelo Firefox e Safari
  >
  > Lista de navegadores com suporte:
  >
  > - Internet Explorer 11+
  > - Edge 12+
  > - Chrome 49+ e Opera 15+ (coloquei junto pois usam a mesma tecnologia, o Chromium)

### Suporte atual:

Através dos seguintes links acompanhe as atualizações do navegadores:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prefetch
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prerender

Answer (score 2):

Este flick acontece porque a sua fonte ainda não carregou, nas minhas aplicações em costumo usar um pre-loading, assim esses "problemas" não ficam visiveis para o usuário final.

Se o pre-loading não for uma opção você também pode deixar o tamanho deste elemento fixo (width, height), assim mesmo que a imagem não tenha sido carregada o elemento ocupara o espaço definido para ele.